# Load data from Cloud Storage to specific partition in table

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to load data from Cloud Storage direct to the specific partition in the table?
I see, that Bigquery have WRITE_TRUNCATE in Scheduled queries, but how to combine it with Cloud Storage?

Or these is any other way to free load big amount of data (50 million records) to specific partiton in Bigquery table?

Answer (score 1):

Use the partition decorator as shown here to load data into a specific partition:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#write-to-partition

Take note on differences between ingestion time and date / integer partitioned tables.